# shell program to build a stack in Linux ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

I am trying to write a shell program such that it opens a directory and then adds it into a stack.(This is Task 4-8 from book "Learning the bash Shell by Cameron Newham and Bill Rosenblatt")

First, I create a variable in ".profile.sh" as:

```
export DIR_STACK=""
```

This allows to initialize the stack when the system log in. Next, I create a file named "pushd.sh" as:

```
#!/bin/bash 
dirname=$1
DIR_STACK="${dirname:-$PWD}"
cd $dirname
```

Running this command

```
>>./pushd.sh directory
```

should update the DIR_STACK variable and open the directory. But this doesn't work!! I mean when I run

```
>>echo "$DIR_STACK"
```

the output is

```
>>""
```

Any hint would be appreciated. (Note that the file "pushd.sh" has been executable by chmod)

Comment: Because you're running the script, the DIR_STACK is modified *in a separate process* -- it cannot update the value in your _current, interactive_ shell.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: If you want to modify an interactive shell's state, you should be building a shell function, not an external script.

Comment: BTW, if you want to store a list of filenames, you should be storing it as an array. Because path can contain all possible ASCII characters, including a newline or a `:`, there's no character you can put in your string to specify where one name ends and the next one begins.

Comment: (...if your book is telling you to build a stack before it told you how to use arrays, I strongly suggest throwing it out and finding a different book; likewise, if it's telling you `cd $dirname`, as opposed to `cd "$dirname"`, is acceptable practice).

Comment: The book is one of the most popular one in shell programming. I should mention that the goal here is not not build a perfect stack but rather to demonstrate some basic  concepts.

Comment: I dont understand it! because when I run the script using "source" command, it works just fine!!